# How to watch for network down -- not using Network Manager

Tags: networking

I want a script that will trigger a script when my network goes down -- or if there is some other change to general network status.

I'm not using NetworkManager.

I've thought of using `inotifywait` on a device file but I don't see what file in `dev`that would be. My network device is `wlp3s0` but that doesn't grep out and none of the `net` finds look at all promising.

I know I could set up a `ping` poll but that seems a bit busy.

There must be a standard way of doing this because other applications give such notification.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly why I wrote `net-o-matic`. Get it at https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic

Comment: This seems to be expecting NetworkManager. `nmcli` is a NM utility is it not? But there is some good info in the script.